# JupyterHub: Disable Terminal using helm chart on Kubernetes platform

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am building JupyterHub infra in Kubernetes using helm (zero to Jupyterhub). everything went well, but I am stuck while trying to disable the terminal. We don’t want to provide users to have an explicit access to terminal.

I tried few configurations including adding extraConfig “c.ServerApp.terminals_enabled = False” and “c.Spawner.args = [”–ServerApp.terminals_enabled=False"]". but it didn’t work.

I also tried by adding additional script file as extraFiles for single user, but it is not being triggered.

Please suggest if someone has faced similar situation and have resolved the same. your help here is pretty much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vikas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try **jupyter kernelspec remove python3 -y** and then starting jupyter with command **jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --KernelSpecManager.ensure_native_kernel=False**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).